# How to autostart a daemon after installation?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, deb

I'm writing a daemon and packaging it up but I want the daemon to run after install. Is there a way to make the daemon run after it gets installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write a upstart job, see [upstart: Getting Started](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html)
2. Add start job command to `debian/postinst` of deb package, see [Debian Binary Package Building HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, that's exactly what I was thinking about (post install scripts) a few days after I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

You daemon init script is located in `/etc/init.d/`

To enable it for execution after start

```
update-rc.d daemon defaults
```

Other options you'll find in `man update-rc.d`.

To run it

```
invoke-rc.d daemon start
```

For `systemd` users:

See [How to write startup script for systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd)

And use `systemctl enable` to autostart a service.

Comment: I'm a little new to daemon programming on Linux. I only see a config file in `/etc/init/`, nothing in `/etc/init.d/`.

Comment: I see, then you use `systemd` see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd) for a soultion.

Comment: Ok, so if I package the init script to copy to `/etc/init.d/` at install time, will this start the daemon once install has completed?

Comment: no, because you use systemd. with systemd you need to use `systemctl enable` see it's manpage.